# is it possible to add a custom table into survminer::ggsurvplot()

Tags: r

I am working on the kaplan meier plot and would like to know if it is possible to attach a custom table to the plot. similar to the one highlighted below.

data # copied from the code put in as an answer and mods notified to delete it as a non-answer.

```r
adae2  <- structure(list(usubjid = c("01-701-1015", "01-701-1130", "01-701-1363", 
"01-703-1100", "01-704-1164", "01-708-1286", "01-708-1296", "01-708-1316", 
"01-709-1088", "01-709-1259", "01-709-1306", "01-709-1312", "01-710-1060", 
"01-710-1077", "01-710-1264", "01-713-1179", "01-713-1256", "01-713-1269", 
"01-717-1344", "01-718-1150", "01-718-1355", "01-701-1023", "01-701-1047", 
"01-701-1118", "01-701-1153", "01-701-1203", "01-701-1234", "01-701-1345", 
"01-701-1387", "01-701-1392", "01-701-1415", "01-701-1440", "01-703-1042", 
"01-703-1096", "01-703-1175", "01-703-1210", "01-703-1299", "01-704-1010", 
"01-704-1127", "01-704-1233", "01-704-1260", "01-704-1351", "01-704-1388", 
"01-704-1435", "01-704-1445", "01-705-1018", "01-705-1059", "01-705-1186", 
"01-705-1282", "01-705-1349", "01-706-1041", "01-707-1206", "01-708-1087", 
"01-708-1158", "01-708-1171", "01-708-1253", "01-708-1342", "01-708-1378", 
"01-709-1001", "01-709-1301", "01-709-1339", "01-710-1027", "01-710-1078", 
"01-710-1083", "01-710-1183", "01-710-1271", "01-710-1314", "01-710-1315", 
"01-710-1368", "01-711-1036", "01-714-1035", "01-714-1375", "01-715-1155", 
"01-715-1207", "01-715-1397", "01-716-1024", "01-716-1026", "01-716-1044", 
"01-716-1108", "01-716-1160", "01-716-1177", "01-716-1308", "01-716-1441", 
"01-717-1201", "01-718-1139", "01-718-1172"), aesoc = c("GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
"GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS"), astdy = c(2, 
23, 48, 24, 139, 3, 83, 177, 27, 78, 77, 28, 21, 26, 109, 28, 
42, 7, 22, 56, 59, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), inb = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), trt01a = c("Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", 
"Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo", "Placebo"
), trt01an = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ina = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), aval = c(2, 23, 48, 24, 139, 3, 83, 177, 27, 
78, 77, 28, 21, 26, 109, 28, 42, 7, 22, 56, 59, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cnsr = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-86L), groups = structure(list(usubjid = c("01-701-1015", "01-701-1023", 
"01-701-1047", "01-701-1118", "01-701-1130", "01-701-1153", "01-701-1203", 
"01-701-1234", "01-701-1345", "01-701-1363", "01-701-1387", "01-701-1392", 
"01-701-1415", "01-701-1440", "01-703-1042", "01-703-1096", "01-703-1100", 
"01-703-1175", "01-703-1210", "01-703-1299", "01-704-1010", "01-704-1127", 
"01-704-1164", "01-704-1233", "01-704-1260", "01-704-1351", "01-704-1388", 
"01-704-1435", "01-704-1445", "01-705-1018", "01-705-1059", "01-705-1186", 
"01-705-1282", "01-705-1349", "01-706-1041", "01-707-1206", "01-708-1087", 
"01-708-1158", "01-708-1171", "01-708-1253", "01-708-1286", "01-708-1296", 
"01-708-1316", "01-708-1342", "01-708-1378", "01-709-1001", "01-709-1088", 
"01-709-1259", "01-709-1301", "01-709-1306", "01-709-1312", "01-709-1339", 
"01-710-1027", "01-710-1060", "01-710-1077", "01-710-1078", "01-710-1083", 
"01-710-1183", "01-710-1264", "01-710-1271", "01-710-1314", "01-710-1315", 
"01-710-1368", "01-711-1036", "01-713-1179", "01-713-1256", "01-713-1269", 
"01-714-1035", "01-714-1375", "01-715-1155", "01-715-1207", "01-715-1397", 
"01-716-1024", "01-716-1026", "01-716-1044", "01-716-1108", "01-716-1160", 
"01-716-1177", "01-716-1308", "01-716-1441", "01-717-1201", "01-717-1344", 
"01-718-1139", "01-718-1150", "01-718-1172", "01-718-1355"), 
    aesoc = c("GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS", 
    "GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 2L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
        28L, 3L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 4L, 35L, 36L, 
        37L, 38L, 39L, 5L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
        47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 6L, 
        7L, 8L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 9L, 10L, 60L, 11L, 12L, 61L, 62L, 
        13L, 14L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 15L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 
        16L, 17L, 18L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 
        79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 19L, 85L, 20L, 86L, 21L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -86L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```r
km1 <- survival::survfit(survival::Surv(aval,cnsr)~trt01a+aesoc, data=adae2)

survminer::ggsurvplot(km1, data = adae2, risk.table = FALSE,  
                                legend='none',
                                title=paste0('SOC: ', aesoc),
                                ggtheme=theme_classic(),
                                tables.theme=theme_classic()
```

table to append

```r
newtable1 <- summary(survival::survfit(survival::Surv(aval,cnsr)~trt01a+aesoc, data=adae2))$table
  newtable2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(newtable1), 'grp') %>% mutate(grp=str_extract_all(grp,'(?=\\=).*(?<=\\,)'))
```

[image]

I see that by default, if i select the risk.table = TRUE, then i get the below table but i want the one like above, which i customized but i want to know how to pass it

[image]

```r
survminer::ggsurvplot(km1, data = adae2, risk.table = TRUE,  
                                legend='none',
                                title=paste0('SOC: ', {{aesoc}}),
                                legend.labs = c("Placebo", "Xanomeline High Dose", 'Xanomeline Low Dose'),
                                ggtheme=theme_classic(),
                                tables.theme=theme_classic()
  )
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible entirely within the framework of ggsurvplot, but you could certainly take the KM plot as a component and create a custom table separately. It's not really possible to show this without a reproducible example though.

Comment: thank you @AllanCameron for the response. Is it possible to append a custom table to the plot generated from the survminer::ggsurvplot, outside the survminer::ggsurvplot

Comment: It would be easiest to merge them if you create the table in ggplot, or another grid-based package, rather than using an html based option like kable or gtsummary.

Comment: thank you @AllanCameron, any example link you can provide to check

Comment: the idea here is that _you_ supply the sample data and the code used to generate your plot. I can then show you how to create the table you want.

Comment: @AllanCameron, i posted the data

Comment: you have only posted data for the placebo group, so the plot won't be generated from your code with this data set.

Comment: I updated the survminer::ggsurvplot to remove the legend.labs argument and now we can run it, Could you please check

Comment: but if there is only a single group, we cannot have the results table you show at the bottom of the plot. Is there a link to share to your data in csv format or similar?

Comment: it took a long time to get that csv into the correct format, but I have it now and will get a look at this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully reproducible example. We start by loading the packages and data we need. Creating the `adae2` dataframe the raw csv took a bit of wrangling and guesswork. You will probably want to skip this stage since you have already wrangled the data into the format you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(survminer)
library(survival)

aesoc <- 'GENERAL DISORDERS AND ADMINISTRATION SITE CONDITIONS'

adae <- read.csv(paste0('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/',
                        'phuse/main/adae.csv')) 

adae1 <- adae %>%
  filter(AESOC == aesoc) %>%
  rename(trt01a = TRTA, usubjid = USUBJID) %>%
  arrange(trt01a, usubjid) %>%
  group_by(usubjid) %>%
  summarize(aval = min(ASTDY[ASTDY >= 0]),
            trt01a = first(trt01a),
            aesoc = aesoc) %>%
  arrange(trt01a, usubjid) 

adae2 <- adae1 %>%
  bind_rows(adae %>%
              filter(AESOC != aesoc) %>%
              rename(trt01a = TRTA, usubjid = USUBJID) %>%
              arrange(trt01a, usubjid) %>%
              group_by(usubjid) %>%
              summarize(aval = NA_real_,
                        trt01a = first(trt01a),
                        aesoc = aesoc) %>%
              arrange(trt01a, usubjid)) %>%
  mutate(cnsr = ifelse(is.na(aval), 0, 1))
```

Now we create the model and the survplot, then store it:

```r
km1 <- survfit(Surv(aval, cnsr) ~ trt01a + aesoc, data = adae2)

p1 <- ggsurvplot(km1, data = adae2, risk.table = TRUE,  
                 legend='none',
                 title=paste0('SOC: ', {{aesoc}}),
                 legend.labs = c("Placebo", 
                                 "Xanomeline High Dose", 
                                 'Xanomeline Low Dose'),
                 ggtheme = theme_classic())
```

This takes us as far as you had got. Now we need to create a ggplot table and use it to over-write the risk table. This is fairly involved:

```r
tabdata <- summary(km1)$table %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column('grp') %>%
  mutate(grp = unlist(str_extract_all(grp,'(?<=\\=).*(?=\\,)'))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-grp) %>%
  mutate(value = as.character(round(value, 3))) %>%
  add_row(grp = "Placebo", name = "", value = "Placebo", .before = 1) %>%
  add_row(grp = "Xanomeline Low Dose", name = "", 
          value = "Xanomeline Low Dose", .before = 1) %>% 
  add_row(grp = "Xanomeline High Dose", name = "", 
          value = "Xanomeline High Dose", .before = 1) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, unique(name)),
         grp = factor(grp, unique(grp)))


p1$table <- ggplot(tabdata, aes(as.numeric(name), grp)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 4, hjust = 1) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", limits = c(-2, 10),
                     breaks = 1:10, labels = levels(tabdata$name)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x.top = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

However, we should now only need to do:

```r
p1
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @Allan Cameron, really appreciate your response. Thanks a lot